# VSCODE "Paused on Exception" in a multithreading cpp program

Tags: c++, multithreading, visual-studio-code

I came up with a problem when writing a multithreaded .cpp program. The code is as follows.

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <pthread.h>
    #include <cstdlib>
    #include <windows.h>
    using namespace std;
    
    void *ThreadFun(void *arg)
    {
        cout << "Thread begin. Id:" << (*(int *)arg) << endl;
        return (void *)"Thread start successfully.";
    }
    
    void *ThreadFunc2(void *arg)
    {
        int res;
        res = pthread_setcancelstate(PTHREAD_CANCEL_ENABLE, nullptr);
        if (res)
        {
            cerr << "set cancel state failure." << endl;
        }
        res = pthread_setcanceltype(PTHREAD_CANCEL_ASYNCHRONOUS, nullptr);
        if (res)
        {
            cerr << "set cancel type failure." << endl;
        }
        cout << "Thread 2 begin." << endl;
        while (1)
            ;
        // can not respond to pthread_cancel() if using the default attribute.
        return nullptr;
    }
    
    int main()
    {
        pthread_t thread1;
        int res;
        void *ret_val;
        int id = 0;
        res = pthread_create(&thread1, nullptr, ThreadFun, (int *)&id);
        if (res)
        {
            cerr << "thread create failure!" << endl;
        }
        // wait until the thread ends
        res = pthread_join(thread1, &ret_val);
        if (res)
        {
            cerr << "thread join failure!" << endl;
        }
        cout << "return val:" << (static_cast<char *>(ret_val)) << endl;
    
        pthread_t thread2;
    
        res = pthread_create(&thread2, nullptr, ThreadFunc2, nullptr);
        if (res)
        {
            cerr << "thread 2 create failure." << endl;
        }
        Sleep(1000);
        res = pthread_cancel(thread2);
        if (res)
        {
            cerr << "thread 2 cancel failure." << endl;
        }
        res = pthread_join(thread2, &ret_val);
        if (res)
        {
            cerr << "wait thread 2 failure." << endl;
        }
        if (ret_val == PTHREAD_CANCELED)
        {
            cout << "thread 2 canceled successfully." << endl;
        }
        else
        {
            cerr << "unknown error." << endl;
        }
    
        cout << "the program ends" << endl;
        return 0;
    }
```

When I tried to compile it directly, it stopped with a "Paused on Exception" error in the "call stack"window.

[image: call stack window]

And the output of this program is incomplete.

```
D:\Projects\Cpp_Programs\book> cmd /C "c:\Users\XinLi\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode.cpptools-1.14.4-win32-x64\debugAdapters\bin\WindowsDebugLauncher.exe --stdin=Microsoft-MIEngine-In-ouoz00s4.upe --stdout=Microsoft-MIEngine-Out-ci0ah54f.agf --stderr=Microsoft-MIEngine-Error-mwm5j45t.fxs --pid=Microsoft-MIEngine-Pid-dmi1kcw4.wyk --dbgExe=D:\Software\MSYS2\mingw64\bin\gdb.exe --interpreter=mi "
Thread begin. Id:0
return val:Thread start successfully.
Thread 2 begin.
```

However, if I add a `breakpoint` at this line `cout << "Thread 2 begin." << endl;` in `ThreadFunc2`. When I continue the program after this breakpoint, it works smoothly until the end. And the output is complete:

```
D:\Projects\Cpp_Programs\book> cmd /C "c:\Users\XinLi\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode.cpptools-1.14.4-win32-x64\debugAdapters\bin\WindowsDebugLauncher.exe --stdin=Microsoft-MIEngine-In-slivj5pt.ixi --stdout=Microsoft-MIEngine-Out-jgple5z1.4to --stderr=Microsoft-MIEngine-Error-gl514cr1.gmy --pid=Microsoft-MIEngine-Pid-g40uu33a.2lb --dbgExe=D:\Software\MSYS2\mingw64\bin\gdb.exe --interpreter=mi "
Thread begin. Id:0
return val:Thread start successfully.
thread 2 canceled successfully.
the program ends
```

I just feel confused why this program cannot run directly without adding a breakpoint in the thread function. Can someone tell me the reason for it? Thanks.

Comment: Please add a tag for the language you are using, in this case: [tag:c++] ?

Comment: pthreads *and* Windows. That's typically a recipe for disaster.

Comment: I'll just add that you should prefer what's provided in `<thread>`. It's OS-independent, and if you ever need to meddle with the  OS-specif stuff, it allows you to do so.